# Create multiple PRs of one PR

Tags: github

Can anyone tell me how to create multiple PRs of one PR? Actually, I've one PR that have 160 commits so It's very difficult for a reviewer. So is there any ay to convert that PR into 4 PR ?

Comment: Are the 4 pull requests contiguous sets of commits? If so, it would be easy to create a branch at these different points and merge from oldest to newest. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic available for this task. Just checkout the PR, rebase the pieces you need into 4 separate branches and create 4 PRs out of them.

For example if you've got the PR available locally, you can do:

```
git checkout original_pr_topic
git checkout -b new_pr_topic_1
git rebase -i master
# choose the commits you want
git push github_remote new_pr_topic_1

git checkout original_pr_topic
git checkout -b new_pr_topic_2
....
```

Comment: But I think why we're not used git cherry-pick here.

Comment: And here what is the master branch ? you're rebasing master branch not original_pr_topic

Comment: @Shubham You could use cherry-pick. Rebase with only "pick" lines is just a nice convenience wrapper for cherry-pick. And no, I'm not rebasing `master` - I'm rebasing `new_pr_topic_1` onto `master`. (or some other branch that's the base of development if you prefer)